# hibernate jpa order by taking time to fetch record from table

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

i am trying to fetch record after some date and ordering them in ASC. i am using paging concept to display result. below is my jpa call.

```
@Query("SELECT a FROM JournalEntryEntity a WHERE a.createdOn>=:inputValue order by transactionIdentifier")
Page<JournalEntryEntity> getModifiedJournalEntryFromDB(@Param("inputValue") LocalDateTime inputValue, Pageable pageRequest);
```

So if i am giving index start from 1 and size 200 for Pageable then taking to much time to load data.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "thoth_journal_entries")
public class JournalEntryEntity {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "transaction_identifier")
  private String transactionIdentifier;

  @Column(name = "date_bucket")
  private String dateBucket;

  @Column(name = "transaction_date")
  @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
  private LocalDateTime transactionDate;
  @Column(name = "transaction_type")
  private String transactionType;
  @Column(name = "clerk")
  private String clerk;
  @Column(name = "note")
  private String note;

  @OneToMany(targetEntity = DebtorAndCreditorType.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "transaction_identifier", referencedColumnName = "transaction_identifier",nullable = false)
  private Set<DebtorAndCreditorType> debtorsAndCreditorsType;

  @Column(name = "state")
  private String state;
  @Column(name = "message")
  private String message;
  @Column(name = "created_on")
  @Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
  private LocalDateTime createdOn;
  @Column(name = "created_by")
  private String createdBy;
  @Column(name = "entity_id")
  private String entityId;
  @Column(name = "entity_name")
  private String entityName;
  @Column(name = "entity_event")
  private String entityEvent;
  @Column(name = "currency")
  private String currency;

  @Column(name = "manual_entry")
  private boolean isManualEntry;

//getter....
//sett
```

er......

Comment: And what happens without the order by clause? What is the time diffference?

Comment: i guess transaction_identifier is not auto_increment value that why it is taking time to load data. if it is not the case. then how to try to remove time. and if record size is 4000 then it gives timeout error

Comment: after adding indexing concept for table. it is working fine. it is taking 10 sec for 40000 record after indexing